# Temporary "jb old" File In PHPStorm And Webstorm Causing Errors

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have a project where I am running a Windows virtual machine on my Mac because the back-end uses ASP.NET.  I do all of the actual front-end coding (HTML, CSS, JS) with PHPStorm on my Mac.  To get the files to save and "compile" to Visual Studio in real time, I use something called CopySauce.  Unfortunately, this setup breaks with JS files because CopySauce detects a "jb old" file associated with whatever JS file I am working on and looks for it afterwards.

So a file that looks like:

```
myFile.js
```

would have a

```
myFile.js___jb_old___
```

I Googled around and it seems that the "jb old" file is a temporary file being created and deleted by PHPStorm (and probably other JetBrains IDEs).  So after the  "jb old" file is detected, CopySauce tries looking for it going forward as long as it's not restarted.  This is when CopySauce starts erroring out since the "jb old" file no longer exists.

Is there anyway to prevent PHPStorm from creating these files?

Comment: `Settings | General | Use "safe write"` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write"**

[image]

Comment: This works. However, now I get the problem: Following errors occurred on attempt to save files: <path to file>(Access is denied)

Comment: Are there any cases where disabling safe write could cause problems?

Comment: @SimonH No ideas. Usually it needs to be turned off because it's incompatible with certain things (e.g. `--watch` kind of parameters for some tools, e.g. webpack or alike; may forget file-specific owner/permissions, will break hard links for obvious reasons etc). AFAIK this option was created to preserve files due to sudden system crash/freeze, mainly for IDE own config files I think.