# Intellij cannot save files while karma:interactive is running

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, karma-runner, intellij-14

I'm running `grunt karma:interactive` in powershell.

My karma tests run fine.

Then I make and edit to a file, and get this error:

[image]

Any ideas why this happening?

I'm running intellij and powershell as administrator.

- Intellij version 14.1.1
- Windows 8.1
- Everything run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

I found this question: [Temporary "jb old" File In PHPStorm And Webstorm Causing Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271895/temporary-jb-old-file-in-phpstorm-and-webstorm-causing-errors)

The solution there, also solved my problems here.

**Settings | General | (uncheck) Use "safe write"**

I'm not marking this as correct, bc I have a hunch that there may be a better answer.